# laravel blade variable being passed from blade to blade causing error

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

In one of my blades I have `@include('pages.partials.plans_mobile', ['price' => '$30/mo.'])`

in pages.partials.plans_mobile.blade.php this line

```
 <div class="plans-table_border">
        <div>
            <p class="pricing-text">{{$price}}</p>
            <p id="billed-three-months">Billed every 3 months</p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

$price is not recognized.

Here is a screen shot of the error
[image]

Why is this not working?

Comment: Maybe your parent view is cached? try `php artisan view:clear`

Comment: @A_funs, tried that and still getting the same error

Comment: Looks like it should be working, might help to see the parent view for more context, and the error exception message

Comment: Since it is a partial, i have to ask: Are you sure you are not using the partial in more places, and it is not crashing at a different place than where you think?

Comment: @RobBiermann this is the only place where I am using this partial.  Do I need to include something else in my partial?

Comment: No as far as I can tell it looks allright. It should work. Can you upload code: I would like to see the controller function, and all participating blade files if you don't mind.